# How to validate headers in Spring WebFlux using Filters

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm very new to Spring Webflux. I want to implement `Filter` like thing in  Webflux. My exact question is, I expect two headers in some of the Webflux `RestController` endpoints. How to write a filter that will read these two headers and if any of them is not present, send response as "UNAUTHORIZED". I have looked at `WebFilter`. But I'm not sure how to handle the cases in this Filter. I have also added the code that I've written.

```java
    public class AuthFilter implements WebFilter {

        @Override
        public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
            HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();

            // How to send unauthorized response if no headers present

            return chain.filter(exchange);
        }

    }
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this would be the simplest, just null checking, don't know if they will send empty headers since you havnt specified any details about the headers

```
@Component
public class AuthFilter implements WebFilter {

    final static String KEY_HEADER_1 = "Name of header one";
    final static String KEY_HEADER_2 = "Name of header two";

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();

        if(headers.get(KEY_HEADER_1) == null || headers.get(KEY_HEADER_2) == null) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }

}
```

Comment: do we have any way like the one in blocking? @RequestHeader("key", required=true) this fails the request if header is missing.